# Program turns black when I switch monitors

Tags: windows-10, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a docking station for my Lenovo work laptop, in which I have two monitors plugged in. Occasionally, when I take a program that's being displayed on my laptop monitor, the whole program will turn black; I'm either using the `START + LEFT/RIGHT` keys or dragging the program with my mouse.

My solution, which seems a bit funny now that I think about it, is I have to incrementally drag the program onto my middle screen (my set up is laptop on the left with two monitors to the right). Once I have half of the program window on my middle monitor, the issue goes away.

As far as I've been able, my drivers are up to date and the firmware for my docking station is up to date. Any thoughts on how to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that resetting my resolution has fixed this issue for me. Whenever the issue occurs, I run a bat file to reset my resolution.